# How do you extract a url from a string using python/django?(use regular expression)

Tags: python, django

string = "http://www.youtube.com/watchv=ClkQA2Lb_iE.......https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClkQA2Lb_iE, eeeeeee.www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClkQA2Lb_iE/vvvvvvvvvvv---websitename.com:1234/dir/file.txt"

How could I extract http://www.youtube.com,https://www.youtube.com,www.youtube.com,websitename.com

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClkQA2Lb_iE.......https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClkQA2Lb_iE, eeeeeee.www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClkQA2Lb_iE/vvvvvvvvvvv---websitename.com:1234/dir/file.txt'

sp2=re.findall(r'https?://+[\w.]+[\w.]|www+[\w.]+[\w.]|[\w]+[\w.](?:com)', str(s))
print sp2
```